# Python: How do I continue searching a list for different elements efficiently?

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, pointers

I have many lists of strings I've scraped and parsed and I would like to find certain strings in these lists using regular expressions. Each string I would like is different, but they appear sequentially in the lists. I.e. The first string I'd like will always appear before the second string, the second will appear before the third string, and so on. However, I can't just use an index because the number of elements in between vary between lists.

Ex. say I scraped these strings and stored it in the following lists:

`personal_info = ["Name: John Doe", "Wife: Jane Doe", "Children: Jenny Doe", "Children: Johnny Doe", "Location: US", "Accounts: BoA", "Accounts:  Chase", "House: Own", "Car: Own", "Other: None"]`

`personal_info2 = ["Name: James Lee", "Location: CAN", "Accounts: Citibank", "House: Rent", "Car: Own", "Other: None"]`

and I would like to grab the elements starting with Name, Location, and House, which may or may not have multiple elements in between. Location will always be after Name and House will always be after Location.

Because I'll be repeating this over many lists, **I'd like to search using the first regex, then continue searching using the next regex from where I left off, because I know they appear sequentially. Is there a concise way to do that in Python?** Right now I currently have a set of for loops, break when there's a match, and then record the index to pass to the next for loop.

If it must be shown:

`idx = 0 
for string in string_list:
    idx +=1
    if re.search('pattern', string) is not None:
        string_one = re.search('pattern', string).group(0)`

Comment: How about scraping the data into a dict rather than a list so you can have `O(1)` lookup instead of `O(n)`?

Comment: *I currently have a set of for loops, break when there's a match* - how about showing that code ?

Comment: You can use groups in your regex and match the successive elements with successive groups. If you want an example where it is used you can look here : [csv.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/csv.py) in the function `_guess_quote_and_delimiter` l.205

Comment: @DeepSpace Good idea, but the example I gave is motivated by scraping lines of text from a website that are automatically stored in lists prior to parsing. I'd have to do a regex search through these lists for the information I want before I can even store them anywhere.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest if it must be shown I've added it above.

Comment: @banetl I like that much better than me writing 5 for loops. I'm still interested in a way to not use break and continue searching though due to the sequential nature of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a short code that prints your requested fields:

```
x=["Name", "Location", "House"]
y=iter(x)
z=y.next()
for a in personal_info:
    if a.startswith(z):
        print a
        try:
            z=y.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

you can replace the "startswith" with regex, and "print" with any other action.

Answer (score 0):

You could you an index counter too keep track of which condition you are suppose to be checking:

```
conditions = [("Name", "John Doe"), ("Location", "US")]
condition_index = 0

for index, i in enumerate(personal_info):
    j1, j2 = conditions[condition_index]
    if j1 in i or j2 in i:
        print "List idx", index, i, "Condition", (j1, j2)
        condition_index += 1
        if condition_index == len(conditions):
            break

>>>List idx 0 Name: John Doe Condition ('Name', 'John Doe')
List idx 4 Location: US Condition ('Location', 'US')
```